# What Python libraries can I use to georeference standard MODIS products?

Tags: python, georeferencing, modis

I want to create georeferenced standard **Swath** MODIS products (for example, [MOD02QKM](https://modaps.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/services/about/products/c6/MYD02QKM.html) hdf files) using `Python`. What `Python` libraries can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any python library to automate this process. But I have found this workaround solution:

1. Download and install [MODIS Reprojection Tool Swath](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool_swath).
2. Use the code below to call MRTS tool as subprocess (using MRTS command line interface).

   ```
   import os

   def MODIS_2QKM_georefence(wath2grid_path, input_file, output_file, geolocation_file):
       channel_prefix = "EV_250_RefSB"
       parameters = [
           '"{0}"'.format(wath2grid_path),
           '-if="{0}"'.format(input_file),
           '-of="{0}"'.format(output_file),
           '-gf="{0}"'.format(geolocation_file),
           '-sds="{0}"'.format(channel_prefix),
           '-off=GEOTIFF_FMT',
           '-oproj=UTM',
           '-osp=8',
           '-ozn=43',
           '-oty=UINT8',]

       cmd_text_for_manual = ' ^\n'.join(parameters)
       cmd_text_for_subprocess = ' '.join(parameters)

       subprocess.call(cmd_text_for_subprocess, shell=True)

       dirname = os.path.dirname(output_file)
       basename = os.path.basename(output_file)
       basename_wo_ext_list = basename.split('.')[:-1]
       basename_wo_ext = '.'.join(basename_wo_ext_list)
       b0_name = '{0}_{1}_b{2}.tif'.format(basename_wo_ext, channel_prefix, 0)
       b1_name = '{0}_{1}_b{2}.tif'.format(basename_wo_ext, channel_prefix, 1)
       b0_path = os.path.join(dirname, b0_name)
       b1_path = os.path.join(dirname, b1_name)

       if os.path.isfile(b1_path) and os.path.isfile(b1_path):
           return b0_path, b1_path
       else:
           print('Не все выходные файлы существуют:\n',
                 b0_path, '\n',
                 b1_path, '\n'*2,
                 'Неизвестная ошибка при выполнении cmd комнадны:\n',
                 cmd_text_for_manual)

   # usage example    
   wath2grid_path = r"G:\Install\MRTSwath_download_Win\MRTSwath\bin\swath2grid.exe"
   input_file =        r"W:\MODIS\testing\MYD02QKM.A2018025.0730.006.2018025192956.hdf"
   output_file =       r"W:\MODIS\testing\MYD02QKM.A2018025.0730.006.2018025192956_tif.tif"
   geolocation_file =  r"W:\MODIS\testing\MYD03.A2018025.0730.006.2018025160439.hdf"

   MODIS_2QKM_georefence(wath2grid_path, input_file, output_file, geolocation_file)
   ```